# Account wrongly deactivated

Tags: facebook

My friend Dee Harris was in a group with another woman with a similar name. After this woman messaged my friend, she proceeded to report Dee's account as fake.
Facebook took it down, even though it is NOT a fake account, had almost 2000 REAL pictures of herself, friends and family, and she had it for years.

She has contacted Facebook every way she can, submitted ID 6 times, and Facebook REFUSES to reopen her account.

I'm just wondering why would Facebook do this? Some of her pictures she doesn't have anywhere else anymore, due to a computer crash years ago.

Is there any way she can get her pictures back?

Comment: I'm not sure what we can do for her if they have deactivated the account.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If Facebook has refused to reactivate the account, there is no way to get activated it and getting back the picture. Keep contacting Facebook, that is the only way to get it back.